# passing environment variables from build.gradle to custom plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a section that defines the environment variables in build.gradle and I want to pass this to my custom plugin.

Snippet of build.gradle as below:

```
apply "myplugin"

ext { 
    lombokVersion = '1.18.6'
    setEnvironmnetVariables = { 
        environment -> environment.put{'RUNTIME_ENV', 'test')
    }
```

I want to see this RUNTIME_ENV in my plugin 'myplugin'. I am new to this gradle plugin development. Could anyone help me out with this? I am using spring-boot project with groovy.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set environment variables from Gradle nor Java in general.

You can however set [dynamic project properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project.properties) which is one way to convey information to your custom plugin.

Since you're already using the [extra propeties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project.extraproperties), you can just set the values you need directly:

```
// Root project build.gradle
ext {
    lombokVersion = "1.18.6"
    RUNTIME_ENV = "test
}
```

Then your custom plugin, you access them like so:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;

public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        String runtimeEnv = (String) project.getExtensions().getExtraProperties().get("RUNTIME_ENV");
        // do something with variable
    }

}
```

Gradle has great guides on building plugins, give them a look.

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html#java_gradle_plugin
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html
- https://guides.gradle.org/implementing-gradle-plugins/

Additional, if you have Gradle installed locally, you can create a skeleton Gradle plugin project with the `init` task:

```
gradle help --task init
```

Comment: In build.gradle   ext {
    lombokVersion = '1.18.8'
    RUNTIME_ENV = 'dev' } in the  myplugin : apply()   i did                                               
    def runtimeEnv = project.getExtensions().extraProperties.get("RUNTIME_ENV")     and i used this runtimeEnv in my task: test as                                                              
    environment 'RUNTIME_ENV', runtimeEnv    when i run the build i am getting                         > Failed to apply plugin [id 'Myplugin']
   > Cannot get property 'RUNTIME_ENV' on extra properties extension as it does not exist.